# How do I make a program open up, and bring the application window forward with Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows-10, task-scheduler

I know how to start a program at a specific time. Now I want that the program will open and its window come forward. I want to see the program when it starts and not see it only in the Taskbar and then need to click.
How can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: @CharlieRB Windows 10